# Imagick shows 0 supported formats in phpinfo

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have installed the latest release of ImageMagick (ImageMagick 6.8.5-10 2013-06-05 Q16)

Along with the pecl package Imagick version 3.1.0RC2

Installation appeared to be a complete success and I now have an Imagick section showing in `phpinfo()`

However it shows as having 0 supported file formats.  When I check the supported file formats from the command line using ImageMagick directly, they are all there an working.  Just not with the php module.

This of course causes problems when trying to use it within PHP.  I can instantiate the Imagick object fine:

`$im-> new Imagick()`

But trying to read a file fails:

```
$im->readFile('location');
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I am running an Amazon EC2 linux instance with nginx/fcgi/PHP5.4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must get 'Parse error' for `$im-> new Imagick()`, don't you?

Comment: You must install PHP module of ImageMagick and restart Nginx.

Comment: Please refer to this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/437765/installing-image-magick-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: Finally, check it with `php -i | grep -i image` command

Comment: @RomanNewaza Actually no, I don't get any parse error whatsoever (using E_ALL error reporting)  In fact I don't get any errors in my logs at all.  I have installed the PHP module already an it is showing as installed in phpinfo and with php -i | grep -i image.  It just shows 0 supported formats.

Comment: Try `devel` packages though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to a problem with the way how the PHP module of iMagick is installed. I would suggest you revisit your installation and install this properly. Then revisit PHPINFO to confirm that you see all the necessary formats.

Install on Debian

> http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2011/05/25/install-imagemagick-from-source-in-debian/

Install on CentOS

> http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2010/07/13/how-to-install-imagemagick-linux-yum/
>   http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=44449

Comment: Thanks... The links you provided did the trick.  It seems most other tutorial are lacking in some way or another.  Cheers!